# Is my Blackberry preventing Outlook from marking messages as replied to or forwarded?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, blackberry

I've noticed that when I have a Blackberry running, in addition to having Outlook open, emails that I reply to directly from within Outlook sometimes don't get the "replied to" or "forwarded" icons on them in Outlook. This is annoying, because I rely on that icon to tell whether I've yet responded to someone. I assume this is due to the Blackberry because it never happened before I got one, and now only happens when it's running. Can I prevent this without turning off the Blackberry?

More details: I believe we use a BES (Blackberry Enterprise Server), with the following settings on the handheld:

```
Email Settings -> Send Email To Handheld: Yes
Email Reconciliation -> Delete On: Mailbox & Handheld
Email Reconciliation -> Wireless Reconcile: On
Email Reconciliation -> On Conflicts: Mailbox Wins
```

The device (in case it matters) is a BlackBerry 8330 smartphone (CDMA) v4.3.0.127, running on Verizon's network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Blackberry and Blackberry Enterprise Server are almost certainly your problem.  I have had [similar problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/68872/exchange-2003-with-blackberry-enterprise-server-causes-imap-messages-to-disappear) under my (slightly different) setup ever since I got my BB.  As far as I can tell, the problem is that BES continually deletes and recreates emails on the server.  In other words, it's a piece of crap and there's not really anything you can do about it.